# Can't install ruby via rvm, Error running '__rvm_make -j4' on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-22.04

I have tried to install several versions of ruby (2.5.5, 2.6.6, 2.7.4, 3.0.0) and in all cases it has given the same error, of course with each version, in this example I only put the error for version 2.6.6:

```
 $ rvm use ruby --install --default 2.6.6
Required ruby-2.6.6 is not installed - installing.
ruby-2.6.6 - #removing src/ruby-2.6.6..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/22.04/x86_64/ruby-2.6.6.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.6.6 - #downloading ruby-2.6.6, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.6.6 - #extracting ruby-2.6.6 to /home/elorat/.rvm/src/ruby-2.6.6.....
ruby-2.6.6 - #configuring......................................................................
ruby-2.6.6 - #post-configuration..
ruby-2.6.6 - #compiling..........................................................................................................-
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /home/elorat/.rvm/log/1652140330_ruby-2.6.6/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

This is my work environment:

```
 $ rvm --version
rvm 1.29.12-next (master) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]

 $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

**UPDATE**

I can't put the whole make.log file because the Body is limited to 30000 characters; the make.log file is 90138 characters long. I'm going to put the first 18788 characters.

this is part of the file make.log.

```
[2022-05-10 07:17:47] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /home/elorat/.rvm/src/ruby-2.6.6
GEM_PATH=/home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6:/home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@global
PATH=/home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin:/home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@global/bin:/home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin:/home/elorat/.rvm/bin:/home/elorat/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
command(2): __rvm_make -j4
++ make -j4
    BASERUBY = echo executable host ruby is required.  use --with-baseruby option.; false
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -shared
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wduplicated-cond -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wrestrict -Wwrite-strings -Wimplicit-fallthrough=0 -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wunused-variable -std=gnu99  -fPIC 
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -fexcess-precision=standard -DRUBY_EXPORT -DCANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN
    CPPFLAGS =   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/12.1.0 
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,--compress-debug-sections=zlib -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.2.6  -fstack-protector-strong  
    SOLIBS = -lz -lpthread -lrt -lrt -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
    LANG = en_US.UTF-8
    LC_ALL = 
    LC_CTYPE = 
gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

compiling ./main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling dmyext.c
compiling miniprelude.c
making dummy probes.h
compiling ast.c
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
compiling compar.c
In file included from ./include/ruby.h:33,
                 from internal.h:15,
                 from class.c:26:
class.c: In function ‘move_refined_method’:
class.c:955:30: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_method_definition_struct’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  955 |             RB_OBJ_WRITE(me, &me->def->body.refined.orig_me, NULL);
./include/ruby/ruby.h:1493:75: note: in definition of macro ‘RB_OBJ_WRITE’
 1493 | #define RB_OBJ_WRITE(a, slot, b)       rb_obj_write((VALUE)(a), (VALUE *)(slot), (VALUE)(b), __FILE__, __LINE__)
      |                                                                           ^~~~
compiling compile.c
compile.c: In function ‘update_catch_except_flags’:
compile.c:1291:54: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct iseq_catch_table’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
 1291 |         const struct iseq_catch_table_entry *entry = &ct->entries[i];
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compile.c: In function ‘iseq_set_exception_table’:
compile.c:2356:21: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct iseq_catch_table’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
 2356 |             entry = &table->entries[i];
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compiling complex.c
class.c: At top level:
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
compiling cont.c
compiling debug.c
compiling debug_counter.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling encoding.c
compiling enum.c
compiling enumerator.c
compiling error.c
compiling eval.c
compiling file.c
compiling gc.c
gc.c: In function ‘mark_current_machine_context’:
gc.c:4377:36: warning: expression does not compute the number of elements in this array; element type is ‘struct __jmp_buf_tag’, not ‘VALUE’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsizeof-array-div]
 4377 |         VALUE v[sizeof(rb_jmp_buf) / sizeof(VALUE)];
      |                                    ^
gc.c:4377:36: note: add parentheses around the second ‘sizeof’ to silence this warning
compiling hash.c
compiling inits.c
compile.c: At top level:
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
compiling io.c
compiling iseq.c
iseq.c: In function ‘rb_iseq_mark’:
iseq.c:252:25: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct iseq_catch_table’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  252 |                 entry = &table->entries[i];
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
iseq.c: In function ‘rb_iseq_disasm_recursive’:
iseq.c:2067:58: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct iseq_catch_table’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
 2067 |             const struct iseq_catch_table_entry *entry = &body->catch_table->entries[i];
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
iseq.c: In function ‘iseq_iterate_children’:
iseq.c:2200:58: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct iseq_catch_table’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
 2200 |             const struct iseq_catch_table_entry *entry = &body->catch_table->entries[i];
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
iseq.c: In function ‘iseq_data_to_ary’:
iseq.c:2710:54: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct iseq_catch_table’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
 2710 |         const struct iseq_catch_table_entry *entry = &iseq_body->catch_table->entries[i];
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compiling load.c
compiling marshal.c
gc.c: At top level:
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
iseq.c: At top level:
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
compiling math.c
making mjit_config.h
compiling mjit_compile.c
compiling node.c
compiling numeric.c
compiling object.c
compiling pack.c
compiling parse.c
compiling proc.c
compiling process.c
compiling random.c
compiling range.c
compiling rational.c
compiling re.c
compiling regcomp.c
compiling regenc.c
compiling regerror.c
compiling regexec.c
compiling regparse.c
compiling regsyntax.c
compiling ruby.c
compiling safe.c
compiling signal.c
compiling sprintf.c
compiling st.c
compiling strftime.c
strftime.c: In function ‘rb_strftime_with_timespec’:
strftime.c:386:39: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
  386 |                         if (vtm->wday < 0 || vtm->wday > 6)
      |                                       ^
strftime.c:397:39: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
  397 |                         if (vtm->wday < 0 || vtm->wday > 6)
      |                                       ^
compiling string.c
string.c: In function ‘str_replace_shared_without_enc’:
string.c:1189:13: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
 1189 |             char *ptr2 = STR_HEAP_PTR(str2);
      |             ^~~~
string.c: In function ‘rb_str_setbyte’:
string.c:5471:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
 5471 |     VALUE v = rb_to_int(value);
      |     ^~~~~
string.c: In function ‘get_reg_grapheme_cluster’:
string.c:8521:9: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
 8521 |         int r = onig_new(&reg_grapheme_cluster, source, source + source_len,
      |         ^~~
strftime.c: At top level:
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
compiling struct.c
compiling symbol.c
compiling thread.c
In file included from thread.c:68:
thread_sync.c: In function ‘queue_alloc’:
eval_intern.h:172:64: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_queue’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  172 | #define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(ptr, mem) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(&(ptr)->mem)
eval_intern.h:170:40: note: in definition of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS’
  170 | # define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(expr) expr
      |                                        ^~~~
thread_sync.c:545:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR’
  545 | #define queue_waitq(q) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(q, waitq)
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c:590:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘queue_waitq’
  590 |     list_head_init(queue_waitq(q));
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c: In function ‘queue_fork_check’:
eval_intern.h:172:64: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_queue’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  172 | #define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(ptr, mem) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(&(ptr)->mem)
eval_intern.h:170:40: note: in definition of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS’
  170 | # define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(expr) expr
      |                                        ^~~~
thread_sync.c:545:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR’
  545 | #define queue_waitq(q) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(q, waitq)
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c:604:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘queue_waitq’
  604 |     list_head_init(queue_waitq(q));
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c: In function ‘szqueue_alloc’:
eval_intern.h:172:64: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_queue’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  172 | #define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(ptr, mem) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(&(ptr)->mem)
eval_intern.h:170:40: note: in definition of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS’
  170 | # define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(expr) expr
      |                                        ^~~~
thread_sync.c:553:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR’
  553 | #define szqueue_waitq(sq) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(sq, q.waitq)
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c:648:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘szqueue_waitq’
  648 |     list_head_init(szqueue_waitq(sq));
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
eval_intern.h:172:64: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_szqueue’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  172 | #define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(ptr, mem) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(&(ptr)->mem)
eval_intern.h:170:40: note: in definition of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS’
  170 | # define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(expr) expr
      |                                        ^~~~
thread_sync.c:554:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR’
  554 | #define szqueue_pushq(sq) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(sq, pushq)
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c:649:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘szqueue_pushq’
  649 |     list_head_init(szqueue_pushq(sq));
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c: In function ‘szqueue_ptr’:
eval_intern.h:172:64: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_szqueue’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  172 | #define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(ptr, mem) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(&(ptr)->mem)
eval_intern.h:170:40: note: in definition of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS’
  170 | # define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(expr) expr
      |                                        ^~~~
thread_sync.c:554:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR’
  554 | #define szqueue_pushq(sq) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(sq, pushq)
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c:660:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘szqueue_pushq’
  660 |         list_head_init(szqueue_pushq(sq));
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c: In function ‘rb_queue_initialize’:
thread_sync.c:761:24: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_queue’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  761 |     RB_OBJ_WRITE(self, &q->que, ary_buf_new());
eval_intern.h:170:40: note: in definition of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS’
  170 | # define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(expr) expr
      |                                        ^~~~
thread_sync.c:761:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘RB_OBJ_WRITE’
  761 |     RB_OBJ_WRITE(self, &q->que, ary_buf_new());
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
eval_intern.h:172:64: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_queue’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  172 | #define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(ptr, mem) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(&(ptr)->mem)
eval_intern.h:170:40: note: in definition of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS’
  170 | # define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(expr) expr
      |                                        ^~~~
thread_sync.c:545:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR’
  545 | #define queue_waitq(q) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(q, waitq)
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c:762:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘queue_waitq’
  762 |     list_head_init(queue_waitq(q));
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c: In function ‘queue_do_push’:
eval_intern.h:172:64: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_queue’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  172 | #define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(ptr, mem) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(&(ptr)->mem)
eval_intern.h:170:40: note: in definition of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS’
  170 | # define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(expr) expr
      |                                        ^~~~
thread_sync.c:545:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR’
  545 | #define queue_waitq(q) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(q, waitq)
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c:773:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘queue_waitq’
  773 |     wakeup_one(queue_waitq(q));
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c: In function ‘rb_queue_close’:
eval_intern.h:172:64: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_queue’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  172 | #define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(ptr, mem) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(&(ptr)->mem)
eval_intern.h:170:40: note: in definition of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS’
  170 | # define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(expr) expr
      |                                        ^~~~
thread_sync.c:545:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR’
  545 | #define queue_waitq(q) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(q, waitq)
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c:818:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘queue_waitq’
  818 |         wakeup_all(queue_waitq(q));
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from vm_core.h:77,
                 from eval_intern.h:5,
                 from thread.c:68:
thread_sync.c: In function ‘queue_do_pop’:
thread_sync.c:910:27: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_queue’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  910 |             list_add_tail(&qw.as.q->waitq, &qw.w.node);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ccan/list/list.h:195:44: note: in definition of macro ‘list_add_tail’
  195 | #define list_add_tail(h, n) list_add_tail_(h, n, LIST_LOC)
      |                                            ^
In file included from thread.c:68:
thread_sync.c: In function ‘rb_szqueue_initialize’:
thread_sync.c:1036:24: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_queue’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
 1036 |     RB_OBJ_WRITE(self, &sq->q.que, ary_buf_new());
eval_intern.h:170:40: note: in definition of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS’
  170 | # define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(expr) expr
      |                                        ^~~~
thread_sync.c:1036:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘RB_OBJ_WRITE’
 1036 |     RB_OBJ_WRITE(self, &sq->q.que, ary_buf_new());
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
eval_intern.h:172:64: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_queue’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  172 | #define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(ptr, mem) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(&(ptr)->mem)
eval_intern.h:170:40: note: in definition of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS’
  170 | # define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(expr) expr
      |                                        ^~~~
thread_sync.c:553:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR’
  553 | #define szqueue_waitq(sq) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(sq, q.waitq)
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
thread_sync.c:1037:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘szqueue_waitq’
 1037 |     list_head_init(szqueue_waitq(sq));
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
eval_intern.h:172:64: warning: taking address of packed member of ‘struct rb_szqueue’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
  172 | #define UNALIGNED_MEMBER_PTR(ptr, mem) UNALIGNED_MEMBER_ACCESS(&(ptr)->mem)

...
```

Comment: The output says "please read /home/elorat/.rvm/log/1652140330_ruby-2.6.6/make.log" but I don't see any excerpts from `make.log` in your question. That's probably where the useful info is.

Answer (score 29):

It appears you have installed OpenSSL 3.0 (which is the only version of OpenSSL available on Ubuntu 22.04).

As this is a major update from previous OpenSSL versions, many libraries  using OpenSSL (including Ruby) need to be adapted to use the changed APIs of OpenSSL. OpenSSL 3.0 is supported [starting with version `3.0.0` of the openssl gem](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/blob/master/History.md#version-300), which in turn was first shipped with Ruby version 3.1.0.

As such, to be able to install a custom version of Ruby on your Ubuntu 22.04 (with rbenv / rvm / ruby-install), you have to use at least Ruby 3.1.0.

Ubuntu 22.04 ships with [a patched version of Ruby 3.0.2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/ruby) which you may also use. Older Ruby versions are unfortunately not supported directly. If you need an older Ruby version on Ubuntu 22.04, you would also have to compile a custom OpenSSL 1.1.1 and compile Ruby against this custom OpenSSL.

Comment: I'd suggest to promote this. There was no help from SSL flags, etc. This was the only answer!

Comment: Answer is correct, but it only points out the issue. Here is how to fix it: https://deanpcmad.com/2022/installing-older-ruby-versions-on-ubuntu-22-04/ Works with RVM.

Comment: Maintaining your own compiled OpenSSL version is something people should be cautious about. This requires that you have to always ensure you get the latest updates yourself in time (which is not the version shown in the blog post) rather than relying on your OS to ship updates (and hardened compile options). Generally, a much safer option is to still use the system-provided OpenSSL and a compatible Ruby version. If you need an older Ruby version, it could also be an option to use an older Ubuntu LTS, e.g. 20.04 which still ships OpenSSL 1.1.1.

Answer (score 21):

I was unable to install ruby 2.7.6 on ubuntu 22.04

```bash
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
```

```bash
$ rvm install ruby-2.7.6
...
ruby-2.7.6 - #extracting ruby-2.7.6 to /home/dgautier/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.6 - please wait                                                                                                                                                                                         
ruby-2.7.6 - #configuring - please wait                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
ruby-2.7.6 - #post-configuration - please wait                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
ruby-2.7.6 - #compiling - please wait                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
ruby-2.7.6 - #installing - please wait                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Error running '__rvm_make install',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
please read /home/kriom/.rvm/log/1654075018_ruby-2.7.6/install.log                                                                                                                                                       
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

```bash
$ cat /home/kriom/.rvm/log/1654075018_ruby-2.7.6/install.log
installing default gems from lib:   /home/dgautier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0 (build_info, cache, doc, extensions, gems, specifications)                                                                                                                        
                                    benchmark 0.1.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
/home/dgautier/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)                                                                                                                                        
        from /home/dgautier/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'                                                                                                                                                                         
        from /home/dgautier/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.6/lib/rubygems/specification.rb:2430:in `to_ruby'                                                                                                                                                                                 
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:846:in `block (2 levels) in install_default_gem'                                                                                                                                                                                               
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:279:in `open_for_install'                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:845:in `block in install_default_gem'                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in `each'                                                                                          
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in `install_default_gem'                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:799:in `block in <main>'                                                                               
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:950:in `block in <main>'                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in `each'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in `<main>'                                                                                        
make: *** [uncommon.mk:380: do-install-nodoc] Error 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
++ return 2
```

This fix this issue :

```bash
$ rvm pkg install openssl
$ rvm reinstall 2.7.6 --with-openssl-dir=/home/$(whoami)/.rvm/usr
```

Comment: This worked for me to install ruby, but once I try to run bundler and install my gems I get an error related to the certificates, I'm guessing the problem is that the openssl certificates are not being detected by bundler itself this is my error: ```There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for
verification.``` Is there any way I can actually update the openssl certificates used by default by ruby/bundler?

Answer (score 16):

Issue command

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

And watch output

```
Extracting openssl to /usr/share/rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1i.....
Configuring openssl in /usr/share/rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1i.........
Compiling openssl in /usr/share/rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1i.....
Installing openssl to /usr/share/rvm/usr.................
```

And then

```
rvm install 2.4.1 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/share/rvm/usr
```

## directory taken from output Installing openssl to /usr/share/rvm/usr

Answer (score 13):

Run `rvmsudo rvm pkg install openssl`

then:

`rvmsudo rvm install 2.5.1 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/share/rvm/usr`

Answer (score 6):

I am also facing this issue while installing ruby-2.6.5 through rvm in Ubuntu-22.04

ruby-2.5 and below versions are not supported in Ubuntu-22.04 so for that I found one solution to install openssl which support all ruby versions

```bash
rvm get head

wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz
tar zxvf openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz

cd openssl-1.1.1g
./config --prefix=$HOME/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g --openssldir=$HOME/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g

make
make test
make install

rm -rf ~/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g/certs
ln -s /etc/ssl/certs ~/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g/certs
```

Install any ruby version with `--with-openssl-dir` option.
I installed ruby-2.6.5 like this:

```bash
rvm reinstall ruby-2.6.5 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g
```

Comment: After many attempts, this worked for me on ubuntu 22.04. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Many of the certs included in the openssl-1.1.1g and other releases expired during 2023, and tests will fail. At present, the latest version is openssl 1.1.1w. I was able to follow these instructions by modifying the version appropriately, so I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Here is the openssl issue which prevents versions before openssl-1.1.1v from passing tests in late 2023: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/15179

Comment: And to give credit where it may be due, it looks like this answer probably comes from this older post: https://deanpcmad.com/2022/installing-older-ruby-versions-on-ubuntu-22-04/

Answer (score 2):

These steps worked for me

```bash
$ which openssl
```

For me, it outputs

```
/usr/local/bin/openssl
```

Then,

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.7.8 -C --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/bin/openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

As your errors highlited teh gemset not created, do in one line:

```
rvm use ruby-2.6.6 --install --default --create
```

or, if it fails, try:

```
ruby -v
rvm list
rvm install ruby-2.6.6
rvm use ruby-2.6.6 --default
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are using the 22.04 version of ubuntu which contains only the openssl of version above 3 but ruby and rails runs on the version 1.1 of the ssl either u downgrade your ubuntu version or openssl version . I rather done downgrading my ubuntu version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).